# Harry Morgan Connection on Dexter?

Tags: character, dexter

In the series [*Dexter*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1444418/) Harry Morgan is the name of the Dexter's father. Harry Morgan is also the name of the well known character actor who starred in such shows as [M*A*S*H](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068098/) as well as [Dragnet - (1967)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061248/).

It doesn't seem "Hollywood" would copy a name like this (at least to me), **Is there any relationship between the actor and the character?**

Comment: Could it be that Harry Morgan is a pretty generic name? However, it was Jeff Lindsay, the author of the *Dexter* novels who came up with the name...not "Hollywood".

Comment: @Paulie_D - I'm only looking to see if there's a connection. Obtuse, I'm sure, but still the name is the same. Even if it was Jeff Lindsay who put it in there (and not "Hollywood"), it doesn't mean there wasn't a connection. The author might have been asked the same question as well, thus why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Couldn't find anything definite, but Harry Morgan is also the protagonist of Hemingway's _To Have and Have Not._

Comment: @RalphCrown - That's pretty cool. Maybe more common of a fictitious name than I thought.

Comment: @RalphCrown And Jeff Lindsey is married to Hemingway's niece! :)

Comment: Hemingway's Harry Morgan lived in Key West, only about 200 km away from Lindsey's Harry Morgan in Miami.  Perhaps they are grandfather/grandson?